# Can't override my resourcers.py class model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am using the django-import-export package. I need, everytime the user send a .csv table, to create a column in the .csv file and fill every row with the logged user. What I did is:

In my resources.py file:

```
class ProductListResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductList
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('sku',)
```

In my models.py file:

```
class ProductList(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    client = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cost_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sell_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ncm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And finally in my views.py file:

```
def simple_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_resource = ProductListResource()
        product_resource.Meta.model.client = request.user.id
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_product_table = request.FILES['myfile']

        dataset.load(new_product_table.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv')
        result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now
    context = {'product_list': ProductList.objects.filter(client=request.user.id).all()} #.filter(client=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'Clientes/import.html', context)
```

My problem is that in the table appears that the value was changed, but if I click in the object, at the admin's page, the user that is selected is the first one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that problem was simply that I was looking to change the wrong variable. To fix this and add another column to the dataset I did the following:

```
def simple_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_resource = ProductListResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_product_table = request.FILES['myfile']

        dataset.load(new_product_table.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv')

        dataset.append_col([request.user.id]*dataset.height, header='client') # This code add another column to the imported csv.

        result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now
    context = {'product_list': ProductList.objects.filter(client=request.user.id).all()} #.filter(client=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'Clientes/import.html', context)
```